# Как переделать условие для *слово?

Tags: php

Есть условие которое проверяет название заголовка, и если оно выполняется - выводит на экран:

```
if ($text == 'word') {
    //выводим
}
```

А мне нужно такое условие:

```
if ($text == 'ОДИН_ЛЮБОЙ_СИМВОЛword') {
    //выводим
}
```

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Много вариантов `strpos($text, 'word') !== false` или regexp `^(.1)word$`

Comment: @Naumov а можно, пожалуйста, полный код условия с `regexp` ?

Answer (score 3):

С помощью регулярного выражения:

```php
if (preg_match('/^.{1}word$/u', $string)) {
    // (Один_любой_символ)word
}
if (preg_match('/^word.{1}$/u', $string)) {
    // word(Один_любой_символ)
}
if (preg_match('/^wo.{1}rd$/u', $string)) {
    // wo(Один_любой_символ)rd
}
```

Comment: было бы хорошо, если бы еще в этот ответ добавили как выбирать по `if ($text == 'wordОДИН_ЛЮБОЙ_СИМВОЛ') {` и `if ($text == 'woОДИН_ЛЮБОЙ_СИМВОЛrd') {`

Comment: @iKey, отредактировал свой ответ. Просто поместите токен `.{1}` в любое место вашей строки.

Comment: Минимализм не наше? код `.` эквивалентен вашему `.{1}` нет необходимости в случае с одним символом указывать его количество =) з.ы. Это не ошибка, просто `.` - любой символ(не 10 симв, не 20, а именно один любой символ), а `{1}` - указание количества, `{1,3}` - указание диапазона(от 1 до 3)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, вы правы, но это уже стилистические особенности написания кода. В некоторых ситуациях я предпочитаю прописывать явно, хотя это и не обязательно.

Comment: @HakuKimura так я и не в упрёк, просто для автора вопроса дополнил что можно писать сокращенно, и что вообще означает каждая часть записи =) было бы неплохо если бы вы дополнили свой ответ, а я удалил комментарий =)